# Computing expectation of random variable with respect to filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, filtrations

Consider a counting process $N$ and a binary random variable $V \in \{ 0,1 \}$. $N$ has intensity process $\lambda$ with respect to $\mathcal F^{N,V}$, the filtration generated by $N$ and $V$. In particular, $N_\cdot - \int_0^\cdot\lambda_s ds $ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal F^{N,V}$.

I am interested in calculating the conditional expectation

$$E[V | \mathcal{F}_{t-}^N],$$
where $\mathcal F^{N}$ is the filtration generated by $N$. I'm guessing I need a version of Bayes' rule (e.g. Bremaud 1981, L5 Lemma, p. 171), but I haven't figured out how to use it in practice. Can anyone show/provide a hint on how to perform the calculation in practice?

For simplicity, we can assume that $N$ has at most one jump, i.e. that $\lambda_t = Y_t \cdot \alpha_t$ where $\alpha$ is the *hazard function* associated with $N$, i.e. 
$$\alpha_t = \lim_{\Delta \longrightarrow 0+} \frac{P(N_{t+\Delta} -N_t = 1 | N_t = 0,V)}{\Delta},$$
and $Y_t := I(N_{t-} = 0)$. Feel free to assume $\alpha$ has a specific form if needed.

Comment: Is there a relationship between $N$ and $V$? Unless I'm missing something, it seems like your formulation doesn't rule out $N$ and $V$ being independent, in which case $E[V \mid \mathcal F_{t-}^N] = E[V]$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Thank you for the reply! The relationship between $N$ and $V$ is specified through the hazard function. I'm interested in the general case where the hazard function is functionally dependent on $V$. We could e.g. start by considering the simple case with constant hazard $\alpha_t = 1 + V$.

Comment: I see! Perhaps you should edit your question to make that more explicit. However, now that I understand your question better, I know of a paper that characterises the dynamics of the conditional expectation of $V$ (which is really just the conditional probability that $V=1$) when $\alpha_t = V$. Look up a paper on exponential bandits by Keller, Rady and Crips. I’ll try to write up an answer with more detail in the morning.

Comment: If I recall correctly, before the jump, the expectation obeys the (ordinary) differential equation $ dp_t= \alpha_t (1-p_t)p_t dt$, where $p$ is the conditional expectation you want.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Thanks again! I will look more closely into this in the morning!

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Sorry for the late reply. I'm sad to say that I found the paper awkward to read, and that I wasn't able to comprehend it very well. My understanding is that, following the terminology of the paper, a 'breakthrough' happens when $N$ jumps, $V=0$ corresponds to "risky arm being bad" and $V=1$ to "risky arm being good". Do you agree? Also, I'm not certain of how the differential equation was arrived at. I don't think $\alpha_t$ can be involved in the expression for $E[V|\mathcal F_{t-}^N]$ as it is not $\mathcal F^N_{t-}$-measurable.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist It would be very helpful if you could write up an answer with more detail :)

Comment: Yes, I think you have it right, also about $\alpha_t$, but that should be rectified if needed by taking $\alpha_{t-}$. Have you tried checking the references in Keller, et al? I’ll try to find the time to write an answer. Feel free to ping me in a few days if I forget.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I skimmed the references but didn't find much of help. Keller et. al. claimed they used Bayes' rule, so the dervation shouldn't be very difficult. However, as $\alpha_{t-}$ is a function of $V$ it shouldn't be measurable wrt $\mathcal F^N_{t-}$. Otherwise, we would have $E[V | \mathcal F_{t-}^N] = E[\alpha_{t-} - 1 | \mathcal F_{t-}^N] = \alpha_{t-}-1$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Do you have the time to write down an answer? It would be much appreciated..